# how to add image to dataset in vb?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dataset

i have method image bar code in vb i want to save image bar code into dataset ?
in frm_Reporting, i have crystal report viewer and put barcodeImage,when btnEncode is calling, image barcode is created, then must to  insert 
to data set .

```
Private Sub Frm_Reporting_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
        Dim rptbarcode As RptPacking
        rptbarcode = New RptPacking
        Dim xrep As DataSet1
        xrep = New DataSet1
        Dim row As DataRow
        Dim MyImg As Image = Nothing
        Try
            btnEncode(MyImg, BarcodeText)
            row = xrep.Tables(0).NewRow
            xrep.Tables("DataTable1").Rows(0).SetAdded = MyImg
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptbarcode
            rptbarcode.SetDataSource(xrep)
            rptbarcode.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try     
    End Sub

 Private Sub btnEncode(ByRef pic As Image, ByVal txtData As String)
        Dim W As Integer = 160
        Dim H As Integer = 110
        Dim b As BarcodeLib.Barcode
        Dim type As BarcodeLib.TYPE = BarcodeLib.TYPE.UNSPECIFIED
        type = BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128
        b = New BarcodeLib.Barcode()
        Try
            If type <> BarcodeLib.TYPE.UNSPECIFIED Then
                b.IncludeLabel = True

                '===== Encoding performed here ===== 
                pic = b.Encode(type, txtData, W, H)
                'CType(Frm, frm_submitentery).pic_img.Image = pic.Image
                '=================================== 


            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            'try 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            'catch 
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can store image in virtual directory and then use Files Stream for convert to to byte array